# Why is my Flask code not uploading data to my SQLite Database?

Tags: python

I have this code designed to login users with passwords using Flask. It is somehow always running the exception in the trycatch. Can someone tell me where is the problem?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False);
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r' % self.id


@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_content = request.form['user']
        password_content = request.form['password']
        new_user = User(user=user_content)
        new_password = User(password=password_content)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.add(new_password)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')

        except:
            return ""
    else:
        users = User.query.order_by(User.date_created).all()
        return render_template('index.html', users=users)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You silenced your errors. If you undo that you might get a hint what's wrong. As a starter: why are you creating a user and a password as two objects?